# “LMB-drag anywhere” in Blender 2.9 defaults to select

Tags: selection-tools, bevel, transforms

Total beginner here using Blender 2.9 and trying to follow the fundamentals videos for 2.80. Videos keep referencing the ability to choose a tool in edit mode, select the object/face and “left click drag anywhere in the viewport” to use the tool. Except when I “left click drag anywhere in the viewport” it just goes back to Box Select and does absolutely nothing with the selected tool (like Move or Bevel or whatever). Is this something that was changed in 2.9? I can always use the yellow tool handle that appears after choosing a tool and the face to be altered, but it’s frustrating having the uncustomized software not acting like it’s shown in the videos. What’s going on here?

Answer (score 2):

This one took me a while to find as well. With a tool selected (like the inset faces tool, for instance) open the *Tool* menu and change the drag mode from *Tweak* to *Active Tool*

[image: Blender tool modes]